# Are pointers in objective-c similar to C/C++ should be deleted after use?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm still a newbie to Objective-C, so I am a bit confused about pointers with that language.
As we know with C/C++ dynamic allocation should be deleted after use, what about Objective-C?

I have a simple objective-c code as follow:

```
bool ns::class::IsSomething(const char * filePath) {
    NSString *_filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:filePath];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isExecutableFileAtPath:_filePath] == TRUE)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

In the previous code, `_filePath` is a pointer to dynamic allocation, so should it be deleted before ending the function?

Comment: It depends on is `ARC` on or off.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: So if the "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)" option is `Yes` there is no need to use `dealloc` that pointer?

Comment: Yes. Think about it like `std::shared_ptr<NSString *>`

Comment: @Cy-4AH: Thank you for your reply. Really, it's a good option.